# " Why am I getting a 'DataFrame' object is not callable" error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, quandl

For the first time, I'm unable to use the `.shift()` method on a column of the DataFrame I'm working with, giving me a `DataFrame' object is not callable` error.

```
sdf = quandl.get("AAII/AAII_SENTIMENT", authtoken="mytoken")
sdf = pd.DataFrame(data = sdf)
sdf = sdf.infer_objects()
sdf.index = pd.to_datetime(sdf.index, dayfirst=True)
sdf = sdf.iloc[9:,]
sdf['sp500_2w_future_close'] = sdf(['S&P 500 Weekly Close']).shift(-2)
```

I was expecting to get a new column displaying `S&P 500 Weekly Close` two rows down and instead got this weird error. He, p please!

Comment: `sdf` is a DataFrame, and you do `sdf(['S&P 500 Weekly Close'])` which basically means you are trying to "call" (as in a function, for example `f(x)`) the `sdf`. Instead, you probably mean  `sdf['S&P 500 Weekly Close']`

Comment: You're awesome, thank you.